# Stop script from modifying hosts file

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, hosts

I have configured a virtual host for an nginx server on my localhost, however everytime I restart/standby my pc the hosts file gets returned to its previous state.

I have a feeling it has something to do with installing a cracked version of adobe cs6 that involved a shell script but it was so long ago I can't remember.

How would I go about finding this script and stopping it from executing? It's really tedious having to vim into `/private/etc/hosts` and type in the same few lines every day.

Comment: I'm not a mac expert, but a quick search indicated that a built-in tool called `fs_usage` can be used to audit file access.  Read more here:  http://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/os_x_using_fs_usage_as_a_troubleshooting_tool

Comment: @glenn jackman How is this done? Quick few google searches only gave me results for VMware and Parallels.

Comment: Nevermind, sorry, I'm on the complete wrong track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet in figuring out what is happening is to use [dtrace](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/opensnoop.1m.html) or [fs_usage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/fs_usage.1.html).

### opensnoop (uses DTrace)

```
sudo opensnoop -f /private/etc/hosts
```

might reveal something as this example during a disk write operation:

```
  UID    PID COMM          FD PATH                 
    0  24386 script          3 /private/r00ted           
   65     41 mDNSResponder  76 /private/etc/hosts           
   65     41 mDNSResponder  76 /private/etc/hosts
```

### fs_usage

```
sudo fs_usage -f /private/etc/hosts
```

would output similar to:

```
15:55:52  open              private/etc/hosts                              0.000085   mDNSResponde
15:55:52  fstat64                                                          0.000002   mDNSResponde
15:55:52  read                                                             0.000006   mDNSResponde
15:55:52  sendto                                                           0.000017   mDNSResponde
15:55:52  recvfrom                                                         0.000004   mDNSResponde
```

using dtrace opensnoop is much better in my opinion simply because it's easy to use and requires less hunting or refining the command to find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was having was actually coming from CISCO AnyConnect VPN Client, overwriting the contents of my `etc/hosts` file with `etc/hosts.ac` on boot.

The post that directly resolved it was found here: https://superuser.com/questions/354902/etc-hosts-getting-reset-in-lion.